# Cordova camera plugin is not returning cropped image uri

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am taking pictures with cordova-plugin-camera v1.2 in my Ionic application for Android. It saves the cropped image and the original photo to the app cache with their timestamps. But generally original photo's timestamp bigger than the cropped one and plugin returns the original photo's file uri instead of cropped one. You can find the usage of the plugin below.

The usage is:

```
function optionsForType(type) {
    var source;
    switch (type) {
      case 0:
        source = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
        break;
      case 1:
        source = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
        break;
    }
    return {
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      quality: 75,
      sourceType: source,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation: true,
      targetHeight: 500,
      targetWidth: 500
    };
  }
function saveMedia(type) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      var options = optionsForType(type);

      $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageUrl) {
        if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()){
           window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageUrl, function(fileEntry){
              imageUrl = fileEntry.nativeURL;
           });
         }
         FileService.storeImage(imageUrl);
         resolve();
      });
    })
  }
```

Comment: it's a bug on the plugin, I think the version on github has it fixed, you can install it from github or wait for the release

Comment: @jcesarmobile thanks for your answer. I saw the pull request fixing this issue and forked master branch.

Comment: i don't understand at all, i have the latest plugin installed from npm but still i am getting the original image and not the cropped one. Any help is appreciable, thank you.